# How to redirect a user to a new webpage after a Javascript Alert/confrim box

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a client who wishes to have an alert/confirm box pop up when a user leaves the site, then based on what they choose, they will either stay on the page or go to a new page (would love if it would work in all browsers).

I have been twiddling all day and have got this piece of code, but doesn't work too well.

```
<script>
window.onbeforeonload = function exitLeave(){var answer = confirm("You have not filled out your questionnaire yet")
if (answer){
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}
else{
    alert("Cancel it !")
}    
} 
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if a user decides to leave your site and go to yahoo.com, you want to prevent them from doing so and force them to instead to go google.com?

Comment: You make your sites uncacheable with `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct event handler name is `onbeforeunload` (not `onbeforeOnload`). See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378802/detect-page-refresh-or-new-load-using-php-or-javascrpt) and my answer (it points to MDN, which has a small example of how to implement what you are looking for.)

Comment: It allows you to forward the user to some other location than the one they are trying to go to?  I would think browsers wouldn't allow that.